# Access inner indexed type in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql-codegen

I have a type that's generated by GraphQL codegen that looks like the following:

```
export type GetAudioQuery = { audioByPk?: { address: string, id: any, title?: string | null, subtitle?: string | null, audio_tags: Array<{ tagId: any }> } | null };
```

In my React component, I want to type my state, but I am not entirely sure how to access the inner `audio_tags` from above.  My first attempt was something like the following:

```
const [currTags, setCurrTags] = useState<GetAudioQuery['audioByPk']['audio_tags']>([]);
```

What's the correct way to type my `useState` here?

Comment: Note that `audioByPk` might be undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `audioByPk` is optional, you would have to use `NonNullable` first:

```
const [currTags, setCurrTags] = useState<NonNullable<GetAudioQuery['audioByPk']>['audio_tags']>([]);
```